# Firestore query within a For loop

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from Firestore where the "simpleDate" field is equal to an array of strings (dates).

So     `ArrayList<String> uniqueDates = new ArrayList<String>();` contains multiple Strings:

`[19/03/2020, 18/03/2020, 14/03/2020]`....

I want to iterate over each query, get the data for that unique string, then move back to the start and create a new query with the next string. However I am having trouble making it wait until it has completed and retrieved the data before moving onto the next iteration. Here's what I have so far:

```
 public void GetDailyCal() {
        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueDates.size(); i++) {
            sum = 0;
            fdb.collection("users").document(username).collection("Diet").whereEqualTo("simpleDate", uniqueDates.get(i))
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()) {
                                    List<Long> TotalCalories = new ArrayList<>();
                                    TotalCalories.add(snapshot.getLong("foodCalories"));
                                    for (int i = 0; i < TotalCalories.size(); i++) {
                                        sum += TotalCalories.get(i);
                                    }
                                }

                            }

                            else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            }
                        }

                    });
            //finalCalories.add(Long.valueOf(sum));
            //i++;
        }
    }
```

Currently this just iterates i++ until it gets to the end of uniqueDates.size() and then begins the query instead of doing the query and then i++ once it completes. I have tried putting the i++ in various positions with no luck.

How exactly can I make this do the first query using the first item in the array, complete that data retrieval, then i++ to do the next query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using the [`in` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)? If you have 10 dates or fewer, you wouldn't need a loop and your query would look something like:

```
fdb.collection("users").document(username)
   .collection("Diet").whereIn("simpleDate", uniqueDates)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply frank! Unfortunately I don’t think this would be good. I would need around 20 dates.